# processing JSON file in bash using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a bash script

```
counter=0
for file in /home/ec2-user/Workspace/events_parts/*
do
        counter=$[counter + 1]
        event=$(cat $file | jq '.Event')
        echo $event
        if [ "$event" = "Time Exceeded" ]  || [ "$event" = "Load Time" ]; then
                echo "Coming Here"
                jq ".url = \"$(jq '.Message' $file | sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/')\"" $file 
        else
                jq ".url = null"
        fi
done
~
```

In the bash script above I am trying to extract `Event` field from a JSON file and check for two possible values.`if [ "$event" = "Time Exceeded" ]  || [ "$event" = "Load Time" ];` is not workign as I would expect. I have verified that the values that I am comparing against are indeed there.

Comment: @Cyrus - ok, reopened - but the OP should add more descriptive headlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check once if there are leading or trailing unwanted characters (whitespace, newline ...) in output of `cat $file | jq '.Event'`:

```
cat $file | jq '.Event' | hexdump -C
```

**Update:**

Replace

```
[ "$event" = "Time Exceeded" ]
```

by

```
[ "$event" = "Time Exceeded." ]
```

or replace by

```
[ "${event%.}" = "Time Exceeded" ]
```

or replace by

```
[[ "$event" =~ "Time Exceeded" ]]
```

to match a substring. `${event%.}` crops a trailing `.`.

Comment: "Time Exceeded". There is a "." at the end.